# Regex equivalent

Tags: regex, perl

What is the regex equivalent of `$string=~/[^x]/` if `x` is replaced by multi-character string say `xyz` ? i.e string doesn't contain contain `xyz`

I eventually want to match

```
$string = 'beginning string xyz remaining string which doesn't contain xyz';
```

using

```
$string =~/(<pattern>)xyz(<pattern>)xyz/
```

so that

```
$1 = 'beginning string '
$2 = ' remaining string which doesn't contain '
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`.

(Actually, far more than just strings can be used in this fashion. For example, you can use `STRING1|STRING2` just as well as for `STRING`.)

```
$string =~ /
    ( (?:(?!xyz).)* )
    xyz
    ( (?:(?!xyz).)* )
    xyz
/sx
```

If that matches, that will always match at position zero, so let's anchor it to prevent needless backtracking on failure.

```
$string =~ /
    ^
    ( (?:(?!xyz).)* )
    xyz
    ( (?:(?!xyz).)* )
    xyz
/sx
```

Comment: I said "string", but far more patterns than just strings are accepted by that idiom. I just didn't want to overreach.

Answer (score 3):

In your particular case, a non-greedy `.*` will work. That is:

```
(.*?)xyz(.*?)xyz
```

will give you what you're looking for, as shown in http://rubular.com/r/RtaMG6ZvWK

However, as pointed out in the comment from @ikegami below, this is a fragile approach. And it turns out there *is* a "string" counterpart to the character-based `[^...]` construct, as shown in @ikegami's  answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20367916/1008891

You can see this in rubular at http://rubular.com/r/zsO1F0nkXu

Comment: It will work in this very specific circumstance, but relying on non-greediness is extremely fragile and error-prone. Especially when more than one are used in the same pattern. In of itself, it doesn't guarantee that it won't match what you want it to not match.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for posting your answer. I'll update mine accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<>) {
    if (/(([^x]|x(?!yz))+)xyz(([^x]|x(?!yz))+)xyz/) {
      printf("'%s' '%s'\n", $1, $3);
    }
}
```